# Snowflake transient to permanent table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a scenario wherein I have to convert transient snowflake table to permanent table and also have same grants and data share. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option seems to be [`CREATE TABLE … LIKE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#create-table-like) with [`COPY GRANTS`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table#label-create-table-copy-grants):

```sql
CREATE TABLE permanent_table
LIKE transient_table
COPY GRANTS;

INSERT INTO permanent_table
SELECT * FROM transient_table;

ALTER TABLE permanent_table SWAP WITH transient_table;
```

But there are many caveats with this approach:

> CREATE TABLE … LIKE for a table with an auto-increment sequence accessed through a data share is currently not supported.

> The parameter copies all privileges, **except OWNERSHIP**, from the existing table to the new table. The new table does not inherit any future grants defined for the object type in the schema. By default, the role that executes the CREATE TABLE statement owns the new table.

Also, clustering information (if any) will not be preserved, so you'll have to enter it again in the table definition.

---

An even better way would be to make sure that all your roles are setup using [future grants](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege#future-grants-on-database-or-schema-objects). This way, whatever operations you perform on schema objects, everything keeps functioning properly (with a few exceptions, like moving tables between schemas), so you could use a CTAS:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE permanent_table
AS
SELECT * FROM transient_table;
```

Answer (score -3):

Not directly, you can either follow a similar approach as explained here:

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Change-permanent-table-to-transient-table

or maybe something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE permanent_table CLONE transient_table;
```

Comment: If you include the COPY GRANTS in the CREATE table statement that should carry across the grants. I don't believe there is a way of automatically including the table in a share

Comment: The link in your answer is about the opposite direction (from permanent to transient, not from transient to permanent).

Comment: @user3738870 I did said follow a similar approach, not exactly the same :)

Comment: Did you mean `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE permanent_table AS SELECT * FROM transient_table;`? The `CLONE` does not work due to the error "SQL compilation error: Transient object cannot be cloned to a permanent object".

Comment: That's a good one @user3738870, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.